# How to pass parameters into Mule ESB flow xml?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mule

Its pretty new this Mule ESB to me. I am trying to pass parameter from the flow xml itself. Once flow started, then doTransform() method invoked and the logic inside it will be executed accordingly based on the parameter passed.

My concern is "**How to pass parameter? and How can I access it from that method?**"
Is there any other way please do suggest.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Using `method entry point resolver` you can call a method and pass parameter.

Share your config for further help.

Comment: <flow name="SendingUserLoginReportScheduler_flow1"> ... from here I need send parameter ...</flow>                                                                                          <flow name="SendingUserLoginReportScheduler_flow2"> ... from here I need send another parameter ...</flow> both these flow will call same logic and will be executed based on the parameter passed.

Comment: How to access that value inside my java code?                                                 Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
 message.getProperty("yourVariableName", PropertyScope.SESSION);
```

you can use various scope here like OUTBOUND,INVOCATION,INBOUND,SESSION etc.